# Scaling tikzpicture then changing scale throws all things off

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=x]
\node[scale=y] (a,b)
```

when setting up a complex picture and positioning everything by hand(specifying all the (a,b)'s) then changing x to make it larger or smaller screws everything up.

I suppose I could use a resize box but I would thing that scale x would be the overall scale and setting it's value to anything would also scale all scales inside it... which isn't the case.

Maybe there is an easier way though?

Comment: Very interesting! Would you mind posting a complete example?

Comment: @marmot Really, it is expected: the environment doesn't take a `scale` option at all. At least, I have certainly never seen any evidence that it does and the manual doesn't mention it. If you say `\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=red]` you don't expect it to fill the picture uniformly with red, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to understand the problem with such a terse question, but maybe the OP is looking for `transform shape`? Look:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{\Huge X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \node[draw] at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw, scale=2] at (1,0) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

{\Huge X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.5]
    \node[draw] at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw, scale=2] at (1,0) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

{\Huge X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.5, every node/.style={transform shape}]
    \node[draw] at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw, scale=2] at (1,0) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will produce (the huge X is for reference, and notice the change of baseline):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`scale` is not an option supported by `tikzpicture`. It is just set globally within the scope of the picture, so that it affects whatever within the picture does have an option of this kind. That might be everything or it might be nothing, but it will usually be some things and not others.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [ultra thick, ->] (0,0) -- (1,1) node [right] {A};
  \begin{scope}[scale=2, xshift=10mm]
    \draw [ultra thick, ->] (0,0) -- (1,1) node [right] {A};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: scaling effects]

In general, this is what you want: fonts, line widths and arrow tips are unaffected by the scaling, but the coordinates are not.

The reason using `\resizebox` is evil is precisely because it affects everything in the box: lines, fonts, the lot. That is sub-optimal by a margin because it means a document with inconsistent fonts and lines. When fonts with optical sizes available are used, the distortion will be even greater because glyph shapes designed for a larger or smaller size will be rendered in place of those appropriate to the context.

In cases where resizing is unavoidable, `tikzscale` is preferable to `\resizebox`, as it will maintain line widths and font sizes, while doing a more comprehensive and consistent job of scaling the remainder than can scaling just those elements of the picture which happen to support `scale`.

Comment: I agree with your comment, +1.